# How to define a Not Null column in CF9 ORM?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, null, coldfusion-9

I tried added @required true to a property, but the table generated by CF9 ORM is still Nullable.

Any way to make a column a non-nullable column?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Javadoc style:

```
@notnull true
```

and if you're not you can add an attribute to the property:

```
notnull="true"
```

When using `notnull` I also double it up with a:

```
required="true"
```

It certainly isn't mandatory - I just think it makes the intent more clear.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSB7BEC0B4-8096-498d-8F9B-77C88878AC6C.html

Comment: editing to add additional information in case the link does die.

Answer (score 0):

### @notnull true

- optional
- default: false
- info: A Boolean value that specifies whether a **notnull** constraint should be added for this column.